# error is boost shared_ptr and class inheritance

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, ros

I am following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki/Tutorials/Write%20your%20own%20controller%20for%20Kobuki) and writing a ROS nodelet wrapper class for my existing ROS node. But I am getting the following error when I am running the `test_nodelet.cpp` where every time I am trying to access the base class. How should I be initializing `TestNode`? Can someone point me in the right direction please -

> nodelet: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:734: typename
> boost::detail::sp_member_access::type
> boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = test::TestNode;
> typename boost::detail::sp_member_access::type = test::TestNode*]:
> Assertion `px != 0' failed.

Following is my header file test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_NODE_H_
#define TEST_NODE_H_

#include <test/TuningConfig.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/RegionOfInterest.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

namespace test {
class TestNode {
 public:
  TestNode(const std::string& cameraName);
  static TestNode& GetInstance(const std::string& cameraName = "");
  bool init();

 private:
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber imageSub;
  ros::Publisher imagePub;
  void InputImageCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg);
  const std::string cameraName;
};
}  // namespace test

#endif  // TEST_NODE_H_
```

My ROS node looks like the following test_node.cpp:

```
#include <test/test_node.h>

namespace test {
TestNode& TestNode::GetInstance(const std::string& cameraName) {
  static TestNode instance(cameraName);

  return instance;
}

TestNode::TestNode(const std::string& cameraName)
    : cameraName(cameraName), nh(){};

bool TestNode::init() {
  imageSub = nh.subscribe(cameraName + "/image_raw", 10, &TestNode::InputImageCallback, this);
  imagePub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>(cameraName + "/final_image", 100);
  return true;
}

void TestNode::InputImageCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg) {
  cv_bridge::CvImageConstPtr cvPtr = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
  TestNode::GetInstance().SetCurrentImage(cvPtr->image);
  }
 }
```

Now I am trying to wrap the test class in a nodelet class in the following way (test_nodelet.cpp) -

```
#include "test/test_node.h"
#include "nodelet/nodelet.h"
#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.h"

namespace test {

class TestNodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet {
 public:
  TestNodelet(){};
  ~TestNodelet(){}

  virtual void onInit() {
    ros::NodeHandle& nh = this->getPrivateNodeHandle();

    std::string name = nh.getUnresolvedNamespace();
    int pos = name.find_last_of('/');
    name = name.substr(pos + 1);

    if (node_->init()) {
      NODELET_INFO_STREAM("Initialised. [" << name << "]");
    } else {
      NODELET_ERROR_STREAM("Couldn't initialise. ["<< name << "]");
    }
  }

 private:
  boost::shared_ptr<test::TestNode> node_;
};
}  // namespace test

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(test::TestNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet);
```

Comment: The error just means that your shared_ptr is null.

Comment: I understood that from the error. Just trying to understand how else can I access the base class `TestNode` in my nodelet?

Comment: You never assign a value to `node_` so it'll be null

Comment: There's no way to access an object that does not exist. In your constructor you need `TestNodelet() : node_(something) {}`, so that your `node_` does point at an actual object. I'm afraid I'm not following the code well enough to know what `something` should be.

Comment: Or as @paffosx suggests you could assign to `node_` before it's first use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that the problem with the code seems to be that the node_ member variable in the TestNodelet class is not being initialized before being accessed in the onInit() function. You need to instantiate an instance of TestNode and assign it to node_.
Add `node_ = boost::make_shared<test::TestNode>(name);` after  `name = name.substr(pos + 1);`